How to change the way 1,000s look on the Y axis in Google Data Studio?
On my time series chart, whenever the Y axis gets into the 1,000s, the number gets split into 2 lines see picture here. Does anybody know how to make it so it goes all in one line or alternatively so that it says 1k?
I tried editing the number format, but there's no option to change it to a 1k format.
